# $split fractions (Ranks like 5/8 to array : [5,8]) in an array of numbers during mongodb aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, split, aggregation-framework, rank

Here is my data. I want to apply some aggregation on Rank field where rank of my record has been mentioned (for 1st record Rank: 5/8 which mean 5th out of 8).

I want to split add another field with title position and add value based on the Rank value. 1st, 2nd, third, third last, 2nd last, last and remaining all as "Other position".

For Which I am applying $split function but it is splitting this into array of string like array: ["5","8"] and i am unable to perform $subtract function due to its type string i need it in numbers array like array: [5,8].

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11b"),
    "Rank" : "5/8", 
    "Status" : "Ok", 
    "position_temp" : [
        "5", 
        "8"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11c"), 
    "Rank" : "4/12", 
    "Status" : "Ok",  
    "position_temp" : [
        "4", 
        "12"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11d"), 
    "Rank" : "1/1", 
    "Status" : "Ok", 
    "position_temp" : [
        "1", 
        "1"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11e"), 
    "Rank" : "1/2", 
    "Status" : "Ok",  
    "position_temp" : [
        "1", 
        "2"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11f"), 
    "Rank" : "2/8", 
    "Status" : "Ok",  
    "position_temp" : [
        "2", 
        "8"
    ]
}
```

My $split function is here:

```
{ $addFields: {"position_temp": { $split: [ "$Rank", "/" ] }}
```

Required form of data:

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11f"), 
        "Rank" : "2/8", 
        "Status" : "Ok",  
        "position_temp" : [2,8],
        "position" : "Second"
}
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44a18c7d7aab074482e11d"), 
        "Rank" : "4/12", 
        "Status" : "Ok", 
        "position_temp" : [4,12],
        "position" : "Other"
}
```

Comment: No dice. You can't change type of data. It's a long known limitation of the framework: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6203

Comment: Any work around to achieve my required data form?

Comment: position field is to achieve based on Rank field

Comment: Only on the client. When it gets `"position_temp" : ["4","12"],` it can covert it to integers.